# Why is this code showing some junk type of value when it shows the correct value on my machine?

Tags: c++, runtime-error

I am trying to write a code for implementing Djisktra's Algorithm... And having some problem with it
The link to the code is     [Ideone](http://ideone.com/0uuUbY)...
When the same code is run over my PC the output comes out to be

> 0 4 12 19 21 11 9 8 14

And the output one ideone is

> 0 4 12 19 21 11 9 8 16777230

See the difference in the last element 14...I am pretty clueless about it... Is there some error in my code ? Or it is happening due to some other reason over online compilers or am I doing something stupid?

Potential Error here

```
int find(int start)
{
    int low=INT_MAX,idx=-1,i;
    for(i=0;i<V;i++)
        if( !(Left[i]) && low>=Distances[i])
            {
                idx=i;
                low=Distances[i];
            }
    return idx;
}

while(start != -1)
{
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if(graph[start][i] && Distances[start] + graph[start][i] < Distances[i])
            Distances[i] = graph[start][i] + Distances[start];

    start = find(start);
    Left[start] = true;
}
```

I have tried finding the reason.. The distance at V-1 is 14 at some point(I tried printing it)  but it is not updated Later(I tried printing it whenever the distance of V-1 was updated) But it seems it was not updated later on!!
I am a beginner please do tell me where am I going wrong
NOTE: (Graph is a 2D adjacency matrix) Distances is an array of int type and Left is  of bool type )

Comment: If you are downvoting ! Please do tell me the reason!

Comment: I have updated my Code and question... With what I tried to figure out where was I wrong

Comment: After the call to `find` in the while loop of `djikstra`, `start` may be -1, but you´re not checking that before using start as array index.

Comment: Without a `main()`, your code is not the required minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have undefined behavior in the while loop in the code on ideone which doesn't match the code you've posted here.  This is why others admonish you for not providing a minimal example.  When `find` returns `-1`, `Left[start] = true` accesses before the start of the array.  Since it is undefined behavior, it could do anything, including work correctly on your PC and fail on ideone.  To fix, since you have a `Left[start] = true` before the while loop, remove it, and move it to the top of the while:

```
while(start != -1)
{
    Left[start] = true;
    for(i = 0; i < V; i++)
        if(graph[start][i] && Distances[start] + graph[start][i] < Distances[i])
            Distances[i] = graph[start][i] + Distances[start];

    start = find(start);
}
```

Corrected code on [ideone](http://ideone.com/v6rWrF) (also removed some unused variables).

Comment: Well thank you.... And I will try not declaring unused variables :) ..... I never got why the code didn't gave a run time error? (SIGSEGV) ?

Comment: You only get a segment fault when the memory accessed doesn't exist. The memory did exist, and it seems to occupy the end of Distances array in this case, hence the corruption of the last element.